# Cassandra truncate performance

Tags: cassandra, truncate

I have been recently told that, cassandra truncate is not performant and it is anti pattern. But, I do not know why?

So, I have 2 questions:

- Is it more performant to have upsert of all records then doing truncate?
- Does truncate operation creates tombstones?

Cassandra Version: 3.x

Comment: Where is it mentioned that performing Truncate is Anti-pattern? Can share that link?

Comment: Its, not a link. I am using truncate in my application and I had to get my design reviewed and in review comments It has come. I was not part of review, so, could not ask follow up question, I have posted there also same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the cassandra docs:

> Note: TRUNCATE sends a JMX command to all nodes, telling them to
>   delete SSTables that hold the data from the specified table. If any of
>   these nodes is down or doesn't respond, the command fails and outputs
>   a message like the following

So, running truncate will issue a deletion of all sstables belonging to your cassandra table, which will be quite fast but must be acknowledged by all nodes. Depending on your cassandra.yml this will snapshot your data before:

> *auto_snapshot*  (Default: true) Enable or disable whether a snapshot is
>   taken of the data before keyspace truncation or dropping of tables. To
>   prevent data loss, using the default setting is strongly advised. If
>   you set to false, you will lose data on truncation or drop.
>
> When creating or modifying tables, you enable or disable the key cache
>   (partition key cache) or row cache for that table by setting the
>   caching parameter. Other row and key cache tuning and configuration
>   options are set at the global (node) level. Cassandra uses these
>   settings to automatically distribute memory for each table on the node
>   based on the overall workload and specific table usage. You can also
>   configure the save periods for these caches globally.

To your question:

- upserts will be much slower (when there is significant data in your table)
- truncate does not write tombstones at all (instead it will delete *all* on *all nodes* for your truncated table sstables immediately)

Comment: those docs are very outdated, there is no jmx command involved anymore.

Comment: Good to know, is there a new offical place where the current docs are?

Comment: Thanks, right now search seems to be broken while browsing works *duh*. I missed that. I should check if I could spend sometime to help if there is something I can do :)

Comment: @ChrisLohfink When you said "there are no JMX command involved anymore", does that apply to cassandra version 3.x too?

Comment: yes, its been done through cql and the messaging service. I guess I should mention it _can_ be initiated through jmx (in storageservicembean just triggers the same mechanism as cql) but it does not use jmx to all the nodes. Also no one does it that way though as its not exposed in nodetool or anything convenient. Even in [0.7 with initial support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12444053/CASSANDRA-531.patch) of truncate it did not issue jmx (used msg service) to all the nodes and can be issued with thrift so I am not sure where that snippet of the documentation originated