# Cassandra - Truncate a table while inserts in progress

Tags: cassandra, truncate

I want to understand how the `truncate` command works in Cassandra (version 3.9) to be able to know what would happen in the following scenario:

- I have about 100GB of data on a table in production on a table that needs to be truncated.
- I want to truncate this table, but at the same time there will be a few hundred requests per second that will be making inserts at the same time.

I am trying to understand, theoretically how would this play out.

- Would the `truncate` try to acquire some sort of a lock on the table before it can proceed? and possibly stop the insert requests or itself be timed out?
- Or would the `truncate` go through in sequence as the request came in and following insert requests would create the additional rows and I would end up with a small number of rows remaining after the truncate.

I am just trying to reclaim space, so I am not particularly concerned if a small amount of data remains from the insert requests run after the truncate command.

I am just trying to understand if you'd expect this to complete successfully or it would fail / time-out.

I will try to run a similar scenario on a smaller cluster, but I'm not sure if that will be a good substitute to understand the actual behavior. Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate sends a message to all the nodes with a request to delete all the SSTables at the moment of execution, you will have information only of those upserts received after the truncate was issued.

In the Datastax [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlTruncate.html) it is stated that this is done with JMX, but looking at the comments of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54072783/6812035), this is done with CQL and the messaging service.

If you are trying to reclaim disk space, please note that a snapshot will be created with the truncate if `auto_snapshot` is set to true (true is the default value), so you will need to remove the snapshot after the execution of the command. Also, note that `truncate` will require to have all the nodes to be up and healthy to be able to complete.

Comment: I think what happens is that cassandra issues a flush of the table, get's the list of sstables, takes a snapshot, and then deletes the list. I was looking for the code, but was unable to find it. Anything after the flush would still exist after the truncate as it would reside in memory and eventually a sstable what was not captured to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for myself. On a 2 node Cassandra cluster I Made inserts at about 160 requests per second in the background and ran a truncate query on the same table that had about 200,000 records.

- The table got truncated and the inserts continued without an error.
- The new rows inserted after the truncate showed on the DB.

Comment: You cold have updated record with TTL  it have done the dame ..

Comment: Truncate will immediately reclaim the space (after clearing snapshot). Updating records with TTL will create more data (tombstones), which will need a full compaction to reclaim the space. As a proactive strategy it is a good approach to use TTL(which we are exploring) -- but as a way to reclaim space IMO truncate is a better approach.